# Quickest way to alter datatypes

Tags: sql-server-2005

A database needs to be upgraded and as part of the upgrade, I want to convert all TEXT/NTEXT fields in the dbo schema to the NVARCHAR(MAX) datatype. The data in those fields cannot be modified, though.

*This upgrade needs to be done through an SQL Script!*

So, how to do this?
(Without having to write `ALTER TABLE bla ALTER COLUMN blabla NVARCHAR(MAX) blablabla`...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the assumption you only use "system types" in your tables you can look up the columns with the types you want to change and call the updates in a cursor.

```
declare @nsql nvarchar(2000)
  , @table sysname
  , @column sysname
  , @type sysname
  , @is_nullable bit

declare cur cursor local read_only
for 
select tableName = OBJECT_NAME([object_id]), columnName = name, type = TYPE_NAME(system_type_id), is_nullable from sys.columns where TYPE_NAME(system_type_id) in ('text', 'ntext')

open cur
fetch next from cur into @table, @column, @type, @is_nullable

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
  BEGIN
    select @nsql = N'ALTER TABLE ' + quotename(@table) + N' ALTER COLUMN ' + quotename(@column) + N' '
    if @type = N'text'
      select @nsql = @nsql + N' VARCHAR(MAX)'
    if @type = N'ntext'
      select @nsql = @nsql + N' NVARCHAR(MAX)'
    if @is_nullable = 0
      select @nsql = @nsql + N' NOT NULL'
    exec(@nsql)

    fetch next from cur into @table, @column, @type, @is_nullable
  END

close cur
deallocate cur
```

If you also use "alias types" you will have to go through a bit more pain to fix them.